# How would I detect and display an HTTP error message(404) on Xamarin if I'm using an API wrapper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently using Xamarin to create a multiplatform application for the phone. The app idea is basically a Pokemon encyclopedia that utilizes the PokeAPi (https://pokeapi.co/) and also uses the following wrapper library (https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/PokeApi.NET). Currently, I want it to where if the user types in an incorrect Pokemon into the search bar, it will return an alert error to the user. However, every time I test it and enter in an invalid pokemon, the application stops and Visual Studio/Xamarin informs me of a HTTP404 error. How would I go about this?

I've tried using comparison statements in where if the API call doesn't find the pokemon name, it should pop up with an alert, but VS/Xamarin will stop running the application and display a Http404 exception. I really dont know where to go at this point.

'''

```
  async Task PullData()
    {
     LoadingIcon.IsRunning = true;

     string newPokemon = PokemonFind.Text;

     Pokemon p = await DataFetcher.GetNamedApiObject<Pokemon>(newPokemon);


     string PokemonName = p.Name;
     int PokemonHeight = p.Height;
     int PokemonWeight = p.Mass;
     int PokemonXp = p.BaseExperience;
     int PokemonOrder = p.Order;

     OrderLabel.Text = "#" + PokemonOrder;
     NameLabel.Text = "Name: " + PokemonName;
     HeightWeightLabel.Text = "Height/Weight: " + PokemonHeight.ToString() +" dm " + "/" + PokemonWeight.ToString() + " hg";
     ExpLabel.Text = "Experience on defeat: " + PokemonXp.ToString() + "XP";


        LoadingIcon.IsRunning = false;

    }
```

'''

I expected it to display an alert message instead of VS/Xamarin stopping the program and throwing me an HTTP404 exception.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call inside a try/catch block

```
 try
 {
      async Task PullData()
 }
 catch(HttpRequestException ex)
 {
    //Shows an alert error to the user
 }
```